# VB.NET functions stored in external files

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that call its functions stored in some other file **not compiled into the main executable file**. For example, there are two functions `Copy File` and `Delete File` and I want to add one more function `Rename File` without changing the code and compiling again.

I want to achieve it by adding a file/module of the new function `Rename File`.

Comment: would a DLL qualify as "some other file"?

Comment: never worked with DLLs. thats the problem with habitual programmers :P i gotta find some easy trick i guess

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish something like this using [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).